# Can Filebeat parse JSON fields instead of the whole JSON object into kibana?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat

I am able to get a single JSON object in Kibana:

[image]

By having this in the filebeat.yml file:

```
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["localhost:9200"]
```

How can I get the individual elements in the JSON string. So say if I wanted to compare all the "pseudorange" fields of all my JSON objects. How would I:

1. Select "pseudorange" field from all my JSON messages to compare them.
2. Compare them visually in kibana. At the moment I can't even find the message let alone the individual fields in the visualisation tab...

I have heard of people using logstash to parse the string somehow but is there no way of doing this simply with filebeat? If there isn't then what do I do with logstash to help filter the individual fields in the json instead of have my message just one big json string that I cannot interact with?

I get the following output from output.console, note I am putting some information in <> to hide it:

```
  "@timestamp": "2021-03-23T09:37:21.941Z",
  "@metadata": {
    "beat": "filebeat",
    "type": "doc",
    "version": "6.8.14",
    "truncated": false
  },
  "message": "{\n\t\"Signal_data\" : \n\t{\n\t\t\"antenna type:\" : \"GPS\",\n\t\t\"frequency type:\" : \"GPS\",\n\t\t\"position x:\" : 0.0,\n\t\t\"position y:\" : 0.0,\n\t\t\"position z:\" : 0.0,\n\t\t\"pseudorange:\" : 20280317.359730639,\n\t\t\"pseudorange_error:\" : 0.0,\n\t\t\"pseudorange_rate:\" : -152.02620448094211,\n\t\t\"svid\" : 18\n\t}\n}\u0000",
  "source": <ip address>,
  "log": {
    "source": {
      "address": <ip address>
    }
  },
  "input": {
    "type": "udp"
  },
  "prospector": {
    "type": "udp"
  },
  "beat": {
    "name": <ip address>,
    "hostname": "ip-<ip address>",
    "version": "6.8.14"
  },
  "host": {
    "name": "ip-<ip address>",
    "os": {
      <ubuntu info>
    },
    "id": <id>,
    "containerized": false,
    "architecture": "x86_64"
  },
  "meta": {
    "cloud": {
      <cloud info>
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Filebeat, you can leverage the [`decode_json_fields` processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/decode-json-fields.html) in order to decode a JSON string and add the decoded fields into the root obejct:

```
processors:
  - decode_json_fields:
      fields: ["message"]
      process_array: false
      max_depth: 2
      target: ""
      overwrite_keys: true
      add_error_key: false
```

Comment: Hi thanks for responding. I did see this during my searches on the topic but applying this in the processors did not change anything when the data was fed into Elasticsearch. Kibana still views it as a "message" which is the whole JSON string for "Signal_data".

Comment: Can you share a sample raw document that gets into Filebeat?

Comment: From a windows machine I stream JSON strings. Filebeat receives it via UDP input. the 'sendTo' sock function will stream the "Signal_data" string to filebeat, The string is the same as the one in "message" that I showed earlier in Kibana.

Comment: Ok, but I wanted to see a raw message to figure out why the `decode_json_fields` processor doesn't pick it up... Can you comment out your `elasticsearch` output and use `output.console` instead and show a sample event?

Comment: Can you please update your question instead, it's more legible than in comments

Comment: Thank you, so you just need to change `Signal_data` to `message`, I've updated my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230271/discussion-between-thebigcheese88-and-val).

Comment: We need to find a way to trim the `\u0000` at the end because that's not valid JSON

Answer (score 1):

Credit to Val for this. His answer worked however as he suggested my JSON string had a \000 at the end which stops it being JSON and prevented the **decode_json_fields** processor from working as it should...

Upgrading to version 7.12 of Filebeat (also ensure version 7.12 of Elasticsearch and Kibana because mismatched versions between them can cause issues) allows us to use the **script processor**: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/processor-script.html.

Credit to Val here again, this script removed the null terminator:

```
- script:
      lang: javascript
      id: trim
      source: >
        function process(event) {
          event.Put("message", event.Get("message").trim());
        }
```

After the null terminator was removed the decode_json_fields processor did its job as Val suggested and I was able to extract the individual elements of the JSON field which allowed Kibana visualisation to look at the elements I wanted!